# Faster version of double_price to int_price given the input sequence

Tags: c++, architecture, double, division, rounding

In a given trading system, the input prices are of type `double`. The minimum_price_increment `min_price_increment_` is known, and equality is defined as :

```
 inline bool DblPxCompare ( const double & price1, const double & price2 ) const 
 {
    register double tdiff = ( price1 - price2 );

    return ( ( tdiff > -half_min_price_increment_ ) &&
             ( tdiff <  half_min_price_increment_ ) ) ;
 }
```

An implementation of DblToInt :

```
 inline int DblPxToIntPx ( const double & price ) const 
 {
     return ( ( int ) round ( price / min_price_increment_ ) ) ;
 }
```

But prices tend to be bunched up, as in typically a point in time orders tend to be sent at similar prices. Could we do better, for instance by keeping a sorted list of last 20 conversions from Double Price to Int Price ?

Comment: What does the first function have to do with the question?

Comment: I have a hunch that you are talking about *my* retirement fund.  That *you* are in charge of it with a question like this depresses the hell out of me.

Comment: I didn't think C++ had a `round()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be inclined to say no, caching is not going to work better. The reason is that each time you'll need to check that the entries in the cache are appropriate for the conversion at hand, and I think that check is going to negate any performance advantage from saving having to do the conversion in the first place. What you already have is, IMHO, not complex enough to benefit from caching.

Comment: Agree. In addition to the work needed, such a cache adds significant memory pressure to the function. Modern CPU's are memory-bound; processing is essentially free.